# Java API for financial data

Tags: java, api, open-source, finance

I am working on my Master's project and I am looking for a substantial amount of financial data about a particular company.

Example: let's say "Apple". I want the historic prices, current market price / ratios, quarterly results and the analyst calls.

I saw couple of posts on StackOverflow about YQL. I think I can get current price and various ratios from Yahoo Finance for free. However for other data, there are companies like Thomson Reuters, Bloomberg, etc. but they seem to have a closed system.

Where can I get an API to fetch various data? Is there anything which will help me get that data? I am fine with raw data as well in any format. Whatever I can get. Could you guys please suggest any API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Yahoo finance Historical data for "Apple"

http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AAPL

There is a link at the bottom to download the data. May be this could help

Comment: Thanks. Is there any programmatic way?

Comment: It would be pretty trivial to write a parser to extract the data from the html.

Comment: @Joel : even easier for a CSV.

Answer (score 4):

A Java library under development is [IdylFin](https://github.com/charles-cooper/idylfin), which has convenience methods to download historical data.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.

Answer (score 3):

Stephen is right on the money, if you really want a real wealth of data, you're probably gonna have to pay for it.

however, I've been successful on my own private projects by using the "API" spelled out here:

http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm

I've pulled down all the stocks from the S&P 500 quite often, but if you ever publish that data, talk with yahoo. you'll probably have to license it.

btw, all this data is in CSV format, so get a CSV reader/converter etc. their easy to find

Comment: could you share a source code of yahoo-data.htm ?

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest a couple of APIs that have financial data that is sometimes hard to find (e.g. quarterly results, analyst calls):

1) http://www.zacksdata.com/zacks-data-api
2) http://www.mergent.com/servius

Both have free trials available.

*(Disclosure: My company manages both of these APIs)*

Answer (score 1):

Good data is not free. Its as simple as that. The reason is that all data is ultimately licensed from an exchange like NYSE or NASDAQ.

If you can get some money high resolution historical data is available from [Automated Trader](http://www.automatedtrader.net/tick_data.xhtm).

You should also talk to the business school at your school. If they have finance masters/phd students or masters in financial engineering they should have large repositories of high resolution data for their students.

If you make your question more detailed I can provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

A Java example to fetch data from Yahoo finance it given here [Obba Tutorial: Using a Java class which fetches stock quotes from finance.yahoo.com](http://www.obba.info/tutorial/fetchingquotes/)

Answer (score 1):

I have tackled this problem in the past.

For price history data, I used yahoo's API.  When I say API, I mean I was making an HTTP get request for a CSV file of price history data.  Unfortunately, that only gets you data for one company at a time, for a time span you specify.  So I first made a list of all the ticker symbols, and iterated over that, calling yahoo's API for each.  You might be able to find a website that lists ticker symbols too, and just periodically download that list.

Do this too often and too fast, and their website just might block you.  I added some code to limit how frequently I made http requests.  I also persisted my data so I would not have to get it again.  I would always persist the raw/unprocessed form of data, your code could change in ways that make it tough to use anything else.  Avro/Thrift might be an exception, since those support schema evolution.

For other kinds of data, you may not have any API that gives you nice CSV files.  I had to cope with that problem many times.  Here is my advice.

Sometimes a website calls a restful web service behind the scenes, you can discover that by using firebug.  Sometimes it will also require certain headers, which you can also discover using firebug.

If you are forced to work with HTML, there are several java libraries that can help you.  apache.commons.http is a library you can use to easily make http requests and handle their responses.  Google has an http-client jar too, which is probably worth investigating.

The JSoup API is excellent at parsing HTML data, even when it is poorly formatted, and not XHTML.  It works with XML too.  Instead of traversing or visiting nodes in the jsoup hierarchy, learn XPath and use that to select what you want.  The website may periodically change the format of its web page, that should be easy to cope with and fix if you're using JSoup, and tough to cope with otherwise.

If you have to work with JSON, use the Jackson library to parse it.

If you have to work with CSV, use the OpenCSV library to parse and handle it.

Also, always store the data in the raw, and avoid making unnecessary HTTP requests so you don't get blocked.  I have been blocked by google finance a couple times, they can do it.  Fortunately the block does expire.  You might even want to add a random wait period between requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking about a free financial data *service* ... rather than an API.

The problem is that the data is a valuable commodity.  It probably has cost the providers a lot of money to set up their systems, and it costs them even more money to keep those systems running.  Naturally, they want a return on their investment, and they do this (in part) by selling their data / services.

(In the case of Yahoo, Google, etc, the data is bought from someone else, and Yahoo/Google will be subject to restrictions on how they can use it.  Those restrictions will be reflected in respective ToS; e.g. you are only allowed to access the services "for personal use".)

I think your best bet would be to approach a number of the financial data providers, and ask if they can provide you with free access (subject to whatever restrictions they might want to impose) to their data services.  You could get lucky ...

Comment: Hey thanks Stephen. Instead its API for financial data service, just like we can get Twitter Feeds using an API. I understand it costs them. I can pay them some fee. Any known companies?

Comment: If all you want is current spot (10 min delayed) and only daily closing prices in history (no intraday data), then you can probably get it for free. If you need real-time prices and intraday trade data history then you can probably purchase it from either Bloomberg or the exchanges themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Google Finance API. (Please google it ;). I am using it for tracking my portfolio. Could you try http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/finance-gadgets.html? There is an example of custom widget and it might tell you if you are barking under the right tree.

Comment: Hi. I saw that. I wanted to use that data for back end processing. It seems finance-gadgets are just for HTML

Comment: ooops... not really.. its a json based service. You can call this in your service layer. I asked you to look at widget, so that you will know if you are getting the data you need.

Comment: Thanks. You mean to say http://goo.gl/jsrFl. Is it not more of a portfolio management?

Comment: Yes, that i what I use it for. Portfolio management needs data on current prices of stocks right :). Look at the section that says retrieve specific positions.

Comment: Retrieving specific positions

To retrieve a specific position, append the position's ticker symbol to the feed URL. For example, to retrieve the authenticated user's position for GOOG, send an HTTP GET request to the following URL:

http://finance.google.com/finance/feeds/default/portfolios/1/positions/NASDAQ%3AGOOG

Google Finance responds with an HTTP 200 OK status code and a standard Atom 1.0 entry containing the specified position entry in the same format as in the position feed above.

Comment: This API is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I kick myself for at least once a week. Way back when the internet consisted of Gopher and all that, you were able to log into FTP servers at the NASDAQ and NYSE, and download all kinds of stock history files for free. I had done it, even had it imported to a database and did some stuff with it....but that was probably 10 computers ago, its LONG gone now.

Comment: Why did they stop doing that now?

Comment: Because they figured out that they could charge people a lot of money for it.